# Is there a monospaced font that have bold stand out when cleartype is turned on?

Tags: fonts, cleartype

I've been facing an annoying problem for quite some years. Since Microsoft introduced the so called Cleartype tech around Vista, IE8 era. The bold display of Courier New font has been terrible. That is, it is very hard to visually tell bold and non-bold text apart.

It is not that I don't like Cleartype who makes many font display beautiful. You can see quite some comparison here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-42-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming . That is, I do not intend to turn off Cleartype system wide.

Anyway, Cleartype seems to introduce the same problem to many monospaced(fixed-width) fonts like Courier New.

So, is there any good alternative to Courier New?

[image]
[image]

BTW: Courier New on Mac OS X 10.6 Safari(with font ditherring) just looks great.
[image]

Comment: can we assume you tried and rejected all of the free fonts listed on that page already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://www.editpadpro.com/fonts.html) article provides examples of three fonts that are readable with ClearType enabled and the screenshots show bold styling does stand out to varying degrees.

- Consolas

[image: Consolas screenshot]

- Envy Code R

[image: Envy Code R screenshot]

- Bitstream Vera Sans Mono

[image]

Comment: +1 for BitStream Vera Sans Mono! I recommend [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page), its more complete variant. :)

Comment: Consolas is a good choice and the default on Visual Studios

Comment: Thank you. BitStream and DejaVu are much better than Courier New on Windows 7/XP.